# Is there any risk or disadvantages of using: git config --global core.autocrlf false

Tags: git, bash, github, phpstorm, core.autocrlf

I am using **Windows** and PHPStorm IDE for web development. In Git Bash, when I want to add (`git add .` ) or `commit` - there would be hundreds of warnings like this:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ...
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

But if I do the following in Git Bash:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

No more of these warnings. Is there any risk or disadvantage of setting `core.autocrlf` to `false`? Or I should not worry? As I already wrote, I am working with web apps (php files, html files, css... that will be later pushed to some remote rep. on GitHub or copied to a production Linux server...). Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it shouldn't make a difference.

Under Windows, the standard line ending format is a carriage return character followed by a line feed character (`CRLF` for short), whereas in the Unix world, only the line feed character is used (`LF` for short). This is what your `git` is warning you about - that it wants to change the type of line ending in the file it commits, even if it doesn't change in your local working directory.

Most Unix systems can recognize `CRLF` line endings fine, but Windows text editors occasionally have issues with Unix-style line endings (Notepad being the most notable example). Since `git` is converting *away* from Unix-style, you should be fine. Even if it weren't, you would likely be fine, as most developer-y text editors in the Windows world can deal with Unix-style line endings.

Obviously, if your codebase includes some kind of hand-rolled code generator (or something in that vein) that relies on specific line ending types in its inputs, this may go out the window a little. But, if you have such a generator, it's probably a safe assumption to say that you likely know the risks/issues associated with differing line ending styles.

Comment: *"Unix systems can recognize CRLF line endings fine"* is **not true** for all Unix systems. For example, bash scripts with CRLF endings on SLES 10 will error out complaining about unknown `^M` character.